# 'deleted_client: The OAuth client was deleted.', {'error': 'deleted_client', 'error_description': 'The OAuth client was deleted.'

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform

We are trying to create a google sheet using API provided by Google Cloud Platform in Python.

Like I've been facing this issue "OAuth client deleted" even after creating a new client ID and service account. I've tried clearing cookies and restarting my PyCharm but i'm getting this same error. [The error is being referred in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9w8J.png)

```
import pickle
import os
import datetime
from collections import namedtuple
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
def create_service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes, prefix=''):
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    cred = None
    working_dir = os.getcwd()
    token_dir = 'token files'
    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}{prefix}.pickle'
    ### Check if token dir exists first, if not, create the folder
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir)):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir))
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir, pickle_file)):
        with open(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir, pickle_file), 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)
    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()
        with open(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir, pickle_file), 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)
    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(f'Failed to create service instance for {API_SERVICE_NAME}')
        os.remove(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir, pickle_file))
        return None
def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
    return dt
class GoogleSheetsHelper:
    # --> spreadsheets().batchUpdate()
    Paste_Type = namedtuple('_Paste_Type',
                            ('normal', 'value', 'format', 'without_borders',
                             'formula', 'date_validation', 'conditional_formatting')
                            )('PASTE_NORMAL', 'PASTE_VALUES', 'PASTE_FORMAT', 'PASTE_NO_BORDERS',
                              'PASTE_FORMULA', 'PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION', 'PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING')
    Paste_Orientation = namedtuple('_Paste_Orientation', ('normal', 'transpose'))('NORMAL', 'TRANSPOSE')
    Merge_Type = namedtuple('_Merge_Type', ('merge_all', 'merge_columns', 'merge_rows')
                            )('MERGE_ALL', 'MERGE_COLUMNS', 'MERGE_ROWS')
    Delimiter_Type = namedtuple('_Delimiter_Type', ('comma', 'semicolon', 'period', 'space', 'custom', 'auto_detect')
                                )('COMMA', 'SEMICOLON', 'PERIOD', 'SPACE', 'CUSTOM', 'AUTODETECT')
    # --> Types
    Dimension = namedtuple('_Dimension', ('rows', 'columns'))('ROWS', 'COLUMNS')
    Value_Input_Option = namedtuple('_Value_Input_Option', ('raw', 'user_entered'))('RAW', 'USER_ENTERED')
    Value_Render_Option = namedtuple('_Value_Render_Option', ["formatted", "unformatted", "formula"]
                                     )("FORMATTED_VALUE", "UNFORMATTED_VALUE", "FORMULA")
    @staticmethod
    def define_cell_range(
            sheet_id,
            start_row_number=1, end_row_number=0,
            start_column_number=None, end_column_number=0):
        """GridRange object"""
        json_body = {
            'sheetId': sheet_id,
            'startRowIndex': start_row_number - 1,
            'endRowIndex': end_row_number,
            'startColumnIndex': start_column_number - 1,
            'endColumnIndex': end_column_number
        }
        return json_body
    @staticmethod
    def define_dimension_range(sheet_id, dimension, start_index, end_index):
        json_body = {
            'sheetId': sheet_id,
            'dimension': dimension,
            'startIndex': start_index,
            'endIndex': end_index
        }
        return json_body
class GoogleCalendarHelper:
    ...
class GoogleDriverHelper:
    ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = GoogleSheetsHelper()
    print(g.Delimiter_Type)







from Google import create_service

FOLDER_PATH = "/Users/manimaran/PycharmProjects/Kalpana-SheetAPI-1/venv/"
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = os.path.join(FOLDER_PATH, 'Newfile.json')
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'sheets'
API_VERSION = 'v4'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
service = create_service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
print(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE)
SERVICEACCOUNT_SECRET_FILE= "/Users/manimaran/PycharmProjects/Kalpana-SheetAPI-1/venv/serviceaccountkey.json"

spreadsheet = {
    'properties': {
        'title': "testing"
    }
}
sheets_file1 = service.spreadsheets().create(body= spreadsheet).execute()

print(sheets_file1)

print(sheets_file1['spreadsheetUrl'])
print(sheets_file1['spreadsheetId'])
print(sheets_file1['sheets'])
print(sheets_file1['properties'])
```

Comment: try deleting the files in the `token` directory. You app pickles tokens, so it is a distinct possibility that it tries to load a previously pickled credentials object.